# Tikz: Listed text over arcs

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-decorations

I want the text in the example to be aligned with the circle, I tried it with `decoration` in the commented line of the example, but it didn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x/\mes/\month[evaluate=\x as \y using \x*-30+120] in
        {
        1/Enero/January,
        2/Febrero/February,
        3/Marzo/March,
        4/Abril/April,
        5/Mayo/May,
        6/Junio/June,
        7/Julio/July,
        8/Agosto/August,
        9/Septiembre/September,
        10/Octubre/October,
        11/Noviembre/November,
        12/Diciembre/December
        }   {
        \draw (\y:5) -- ++(\y:0.4);
        \node [anchor=west,rotate=\y-90] at (\y:5.2) {\month};
        \node [anchor=west,rotate=\y-90] at (\y:5.6) {\mes};
        \draw   (\y:4.9) arc[start angle =\y, end angle=\y-20,radius=4.2];
%       \draw   (\y:4.9) arc[decorate,decoration={\month},start angle =\y, end angle=\y-20,radius=4.2];
        }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Listed months]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple corection of angles, which put test on tangents to arc's:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x/\mes/\month[evaluate=\x as \y using \x*-30+120] in
        {
        1/Enero/January,
        2/Febrero/February,
        3/Marzo/March,
        4/Abril/April,
        5/Mayo/May,
        6/Junio/June,
        7/Julio/July,
        8/Agosto/August,
        9/Septiembre/September,
        10/Octubre/October,
        11/Noviembre/November,
        12/Diciembre/December
        }   {
        \draw (\y:5) -- ++(\y:0.4);
        \node [anchor=south,rotate=\y-100] at (\y-10:5) {\month}; % <---
        \node [anchor=south,rotate=\y-100] at (\y-10:5.4) {\mes}; % <---
        \draw   (\y:4.9) arc[start angle =\y, end angle=\y-20,radius=4.8];
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

With use of the TikZ library `decorations.text` is possible decorate path with text:

**Edit:** Text is now left aligned with small indent (`2pt`) on the left that start of text do not touch radial line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    decoration={text along path,
    text align={left,left indent=2pt}}]
    \foreach \x/\mes/\month[evaluate=\x as \y using \x*-30+120] in
        {
        1/Enero/January,
        2/Febrero/February,
        3/Marzo/March,
        4/Abril/April,
        5/Mayo/May,
        6/Junio/June,
        7/Julio/July,
        8/Agosto/August,
        9/Septiembre/September,
        10/Octubre/October,
        11/Noviembre/November,
        12/Diciembre/December
        }   {
        \draw (\y:5) -- ++ (\y:0.4);
        \draw   (\y:4.9) arc[start angle =\y, end angle=\y-20,radius=4.8];

        \draw [decorate,
               decoration={text={\mes}}]               
               (\y:5)  arc [start angle =\y, end angle=\y-20,radius=4.8];
        \draw [decorate,
               decoration={text={\mes}}]
               (\y:5.4)  arc [start angle =\y, end angle=\y-20,radius=4.8];
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good but i want the text aligned to its left, in the radial line.

Comment: @Pillqu, sorry, I was interrupted at writing of answer. Now it is complete.

Comment: Changing align=left i have what i want :-)

Comment: @Pillqu, I slightly improve code that it is now a bit shorter.

Comment: @Pillqu, in this case you can drop out `text align` :-)